# Trouble getting CSS code to link to the HTML file

Tags: html, css

First off, sorry to be asking this as I know it's a common question/problem brought up on here - but after researching and looking at the other threads and trying to apply those solutions I'm still at a loss. Hoping that by posting my code I can get the help I need. Thank you in advance.

As it says in the subject line I cannot get the .css file to link to the .html file. I'm a few days into learning via modules on LinkedIn and this code actually comes from one of those modules, making it more confusing that it's not working. Both the html and css file are in the same folder on my desktop, and I've quadruple checked that the .css file is the correct name. Here's the top part of the code with the problem area:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Mat Alano-Martin Test Page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css">
</head>
<body>
```

Comment: `href="css/styles.css"` will look for a file named `styles.css` in the `css/` directory. You said both files are in the same directory; so either remove the `css/` part from your link tag or create said directory and move your .css file there.

Comment: @high-rolls Thank you. The folder I had them both in was called css (I think I moved the html file in there as part of one of my other attempts at fixing it) but deleting that directory portion fixed it. Thanks so much.